# Как изменить кодировку в БД?

Tags: sql, oracle

Имеется БД Oracle, в которой `nls_lang` установленa как `russian_russia`. Необходимо поменять кодировку на `american`.

Проверяю кодировку так:

```
select * from nls_database_parameters
```

Пробовал изменить реестр и установить кодировку, что мне нужна. Пробовал прописать `set nls_lang = american_america`, но ничего не работает. Переустанавливать не хочется.

Может есть работающие алгоритмы смены кодировки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установкой переменной окружения `NLS_LANG` изменится окружение только для клиентских программ. Никаких изменений в БД при этом не произойдёт.

Значение `american_america` установит `NLS_LANGUAGE` и `NLS_TERRITORY` для текушего соединения клиентской программы. Ни к кодировке установленной в клиенте, ни тем более установленной в БД, эти два параметра не имеют никакого отношения.

---

Переменная `NLS_LANG` не используется в серверной части БД. Для изменения национальных настроек надо в файле параметров БД init.ora прописать отдельно:

- `NLS_LANGUAGE` - язык
- `NLS_TERRITORY` -территории
- `NLS_CHARACTERSET` - кодировка

Кодировкa устанавливается только параметром `NLS_CHARACTERSET`.
Уже установленную кодировку можно изменить только, если новая кодировка является строгим супермножеством старой кодировки.
Например, нельзя поменять `WE8ISO8859P5` на `AL32UTF8`, а `US7ASCII` на любую можно всегда.

Если повезло, то `alter database character set AL32UTF8;`.
Если нет - миграция данных и в худшем случае программ, которые не совсем понимают новую кодировку.

Подробнее читаем [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011), или в общих чертах по-русски [тут](http://www.read-and-think.org/oracle_globalization_support_russian_cyrillic.html).

Comment: а если я уже установил ДБ с кодировкой и хочу ее поменять? Пробовал в init.ora изменить NLS_LANGUAGE, NLS_TERRITORY, а так же поправить запись в реестре, но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: В таком случае всё грустнее. В общем случае - импорт и экспорт в новую БД. Есть ещё специальный скрипт. Почитать можно тут: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch11charsetmig.htm

Comment: Спасибо @hinotf,  был на работе,  не мог отписаться

Comment: @voipp Так вам нужен NLS_CHARACTERSET, те 3-я составляющая NLS_LANG. Какой стоит сейчас и какой желаемый?